# Yandex map на android

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api

Может, кто знает как реализовать yandex map на android, чтобы она работала быстро и без лагов? Пробовал использовать yandex mapkit библиотеку, но что-то там не все гладко работает, затем пробовал через API, и выводить в WebView, но снова есть проблемы. Как-то это все не то, либо я плохо реализовал.

Хочу добиться такого же результата, как в этом приложении: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.taximaster.tmtaxicaller.id0960&hl=ru

Может, кто знает, как там реализована карта yandex?

p.s Есть подозрения что  приложения использует карту osm и накладывает на ней тайлы yandex map

Comment: Ну так на webview и реализовано. А какие проблемы с webview ?

Comment: @ШуткоАлександр При использовании WebView и API 2.0 есть что то типа авто коррекции. Когда пальцем передвигаешь карту а затем убираешь палец она не остается в том же положении (немного смещается сома). Можно ли убрать данный эффект? Если рать API 2.1 то тут + к коррекции отрисовка карты происходит после того как убираешь палец (получается эффект что двигаешь картинки).

Comment: Никогда такого эффекта не наблюдал. Куда перемещаешь там и остается. Видимо особенности вашей реализации..

Comment: @ШуткоАлександр, Вы бы не могли мне показать обычный пример вывода карты на android studio? Может что я не так делал. Какой API версии вы используете?

Comment: Только завтра. Сейчас я с телефона пишу. Кода под рукой нет.

Comment: @ШуткоАлександр, спасибо. Буду ждать. Свой тоже не могу сегодня показать. Завтра скину тоже.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конкретно в указанном приложении такси реализовано судя по всему через какой-то свой велосипед, либо это mapkit обработанный напильником (в выводе device monitor в разметке webview отсутствует, а карта лежит в обычном View). Через WebView по моему опыту тоже вполне себе неплохо работает.

В общем вот реализация вывода карты (инициализация вида):

```
mapWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mapWebView);
mapWebView.addJavascriptInterface(mapJSInterface, "MyApp");
WebSettings webSettings = mapWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

try {
    InputStream is = getAssets().open("map.html");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
    if (is.read(buffer) <= 0) Logger.Warn("Can't read embedded assets map.html file!");
    is.close();

    String htmlText = new String(buffer);
    mapWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://ru.yandex.api.yandexmapswebviewexample.ymapapp",
            htmlText, "text/html", "UTF-8", null
    );
} catch (IOException e) {
    Logger.Exception(e);
}

webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```

Здесь собственно html файл (я поубирал кастомные кнопки и обработчики):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height, user-scalable=no"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ymaps.ready(init_map);
        var myMap;
        var _ymapZoomPromise = null;

        function init_map() {
            var myPlacemark;
            MyApp.OnPageLoaded();

            myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                center: [48.47655, 135.064308],
                zoom: 6,
                controls: [],
                behaviors: ["default", "scrollZoom"]
            }, {
                suppressMapOpenBlock: true,
            });

            myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
                var coords = e.get('coords');
                // putBaloon(coords);
            });
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        * {
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-drag: none;
            -webkit-user-modify: unset;
        }

        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Здесь `MyApp.OnPageLoaded();` javascript интерфейс в приложение. При вызове прячет прогресс-бар загрузки и отображает скрытый WebView. Вот в таком варианте проверял на 4.0/4.1/4.2/5/6 версиях как на реальном железе так и на эмуляторах. Вполне себе плавно работает и не дергается даже на слабом железе. Единственный минус - загрузка вида занимает не менее 4 секунд.

Есть варианты оптимизации - грузить не весь JS API, а только нужные модули.

Comment: Что такое mapJSInterface?

Comment: Это класс для взаимодействия с кодом приложения. Там внутри инициализация GPS и методы вроде     @JavascriptInterface
    public void OnPageLoaded() {
        if (locationListener != null) locationListener.OnPageLoaded();
    } ну и JS код внутри webview вызывает их. А тот же OnPageLoaded прячет прогресс-бар загрузки и показывает саму карту

Comment: Когда резко палец убираешь карта сома пододвигается. От этого не как не избавиться. Создается эффект что карта лагает.

Остановился на YMK удалось оптимизировать карту.

Comment: У меня ни на одной платформе такого эффекта нет. Как воспроизвести?